# C# Specification pattern agregate checker

Tags: c#, specifications

I have created class that intend to check is Generic T meets all the required specifications. Need help to agregate them and return boolean value.

Here is the base specification class

```
/// <summary>
/// Base spec
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public abstract class BaseSpecification<T>
{
    public abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression();

    /// <summary>
    /// Meets
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Meets(T entity)
    {
        Func<T, bool> predicate = ToExpression().Compile();
        return predicate(entity);
    }
}
```

And concrete specification that inhereits from base:

```
public class DeviceIsActiveSpecification : BaseSpecification<Device>
{
    public override Expression<Func<Device, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        //Устройство поддерживает выполнение команд (Активное)
        return device => device.DeviceActivityType == DeviceActivityType.Active;
    }
}
```

And the validator class that has to check is T meets all the cpecifications:

```
public class SpecificationValidator<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cpec list
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IList<BaseSpecification<T>> _specifications2Meet;

    public SpecificationValidator()
    {
        _specifications2Meet = new List<BaseSpecification<T>>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add cpec
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSecification"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public SpecificationValidator<T> Add<TSecification>() where TSecification : BaseSpecification<T>, new()
    {
        return Add(new TSecification());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="specification"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    SpecificationValidator<T> Add(BaseSpecification<T> specification)
    {
        if (specification == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specification));
        _specifications2Meet.Add(specification);
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Meets all
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool MeetsAllSpecifications (T source)
    {
        ??? Need help here to agregate "Meets" 
    }
}
```

Intended usage:

```
var validator = new SpecificationValidator<Device>()
            .Add<DeviceIsActiveSpecification>()
            .Add<CommunicationDeviceSpecification>()
            .MeetsAllSpecifications(device);
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I missed something, but it seems you can simply use LINQ's [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all) here:

```
public bool MeetsAllSpecifications (T source)
{
    return specifications2Meet.All(spec => spec.Meets(source));
}
```